# Unable to resolve some functions from ntdll and kernel32

Tags: winapi

On one particular Windows 7 64-bit machine I can't resolve some system functions from ntdll.dll and kernel32.dll: GlobalMemoryStatusEx, GetProcessMemoryInfo, NtQuerySystemInformation.

```
typedef void (WINAPI *PFN_GLOBAL_MEMORY_STATUS_EX) (MEMORYSTATUSEX *lpBuffer);

PFN_GLOBAL_MEMORY_STATUS_EX pfnGlobalMemoryStatusEx = 
    (PFN_GLOBAL_MEMORY_STATUS_EX)QLibrary::resolve("Kernel32.dll","GlobalMemoryStatusEx");
if(!pfnGlobalMemoryStatusEx)
    qWarning() << "GlobalMemoryStatusEx failed -" << ::GetLastError();
```

The above code returns error 127 = ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND, while it works like a charm on thousands of other PCs running any Windows version.

I really doubt these functions are actually **missing**. What in the world could kind of *block* them?

It's a Qt/MinGW app by the way.

Comment: Can you offer us a [mcve].

Comment: obviously something wrong with this specific machine. impossible get generic answer. only need debug (or test )on this specific machine. the best way of course debug. if impossible try `GetProcAddress` or `LdrGetProcedureAddress` or direct parse PE export for view result. or forget this machine. on one from thousands  PC always can something wrong happened

Answer (score 0):

The question is difficult to give a complete answer to because you did not follow the proper steps of checking yourself and posting the results. However, I will give it my best attempt to walk you through what I would do:

> I really doubt these functions are actually missing.

Did you actually check? If you have access to the machine, download a PE parsing program, such as [PE Studio](https://www.winitor.com/) (free) and then go to the system's Windows\System32 directory. Now, copy NtDll.dll and kernel32.dll onto the desktop. Finally, drag the copied versions onto PE Studio and click the "exports" section on the left navigation pane.

Check for the functions that you stated were missing. You can alphabetize them to make them easier.

If the functions are there, that means that there is some other problem with the symbol resolution and/or relocation going on, most likely in the PE Ldr functions as @RbMm stated in the comments. You can figure this out by using WinDbg. First, install [Windows Debugging Tools](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit) (install the whole WDK but just uncheck everything except the tools). Next, open up "Global Flags" application by pressing the Windows key and typing in Global Flags or "gflags." Finally, go to the "Image File" tab in Global Flags and click in the only text box available. Press TAB to refresh, then type the name of your application into the box, *tick Show Loader Snaps*, then hit Apply/OK. Finally, open up WinDbg and then use it to debug your program and it will spit out everything the loader does. You will have probably like 20,000 lines of loader code, but you will be able to see what's going wrong and at which step it is happening.

If you don't have access to the machine, you'll have to try and use a VM of the same Windows build to reproduce the problem or at least examine... Alternatively, you could examine a crash dump from the machine.